# How to read controls inside a span : Both span and controls are dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span which is created dynamically

```
var spanconent= <SPAN class=editable><INPUT id=name class="textobx " title=user value=U maxLength=1 ></SPAN>
```

how to read the input id .

Please me out .

Thanks,

Comment: This is the span content  var spanconent= <SPAN class=editable><INPUT id=name class="textobx " title=user value=U maxLength=1 ></SPAN> .

Comment: How are you dynamically creating the span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input').attr('id');
```

[Referens](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

Comment: sorry I  am a new  user , thanks very much it worked for me , Thanks once again

Comment: @MathieuF oh yes this answer will. See OP:s comment under mine? He says that this answer provides result to his question. Var `spanconent` is probably appended to page by js, so this answer is fully acceptable. I have no idea what are you talking about in your other sentence..

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcUL3/)

```
$(spanconent).find('input').get(0).id
```

Otherwise, take care to explain